# DMS -get notified when replication task is completed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I need a way to get notified when the task finished rather it `failed` or `Load complete`

```
const dms : AWS.DMS;

const params = {
        StartReplicationTaskType: "reload-target",
        ReplicationTaskArn:
          "MyArn",
      };

dms.startReplicationTask(
          params,
          (err: AWS.AWSError, data: AWS.DMS.StartReplicationTaskResponse) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("failed_with_error", err);
             
            }
            if (data) {
              console.log("success ", data);
             
            }
          }
        );
```

after the task started I got response on the `data` object with `status: starting`
but it's not updated with the other status.

I tried `waitFor` to track status changing but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create event subscription under **DMS** --> **Event subscriptions**

then create Lambda function triggered by that event subscription